# Allowing Facebook login through Firebase on Cordova

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, authentication, firebase

I am attempting to implement social Facebook login (managed through firebase) on a Cordova app, by using the cordova in-app-browser plugin. When I try to login on my device (iOS), the in-app-browser correctly brings up the Facebook login, but I receive the Facebook error:

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

I've seen this error before and I know it's because I need to whitelist a domain in order for it to access my Facebook app, **but what do I whitelist if the request is coming from a cordova app on a mobile device?**

I've browsed other posts that suggested using the cordova Facebook plugin, but this would then login directly on the app, and not register that the user is facebook-logged-in on Firebase (which I need for data and user management).

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
      var login =  function(provider) {
ref.authWithOAuthPopup(provider, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    // an error occurred while attempting login
console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  } else {
    // user authenticated with Firebase
    // var message = 'User ID: ' + authData.uid + ', Provider: ' + authData.provider;
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

High five for finding my own answer by reading the documentation.

From: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html#section-configure

> In your Facebook app configuration, click on the Settings tab on the
>   left-hand navigation menu. Then go to the Advanced tab at the top and
>   scroll down to the Client OAuth Settings section. At the bottom of
>   that section, add
>   https://auth.firebase.com/v2/(YOUR-FIREBASE-APP)/auth/facebook/callback
>   to your Valid OAuth redirect URIs and click Save Changes at the bottom
>   of the page.